# Multiply distributions in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am new to Tensorflow and I want to multiply two distributions to get posterior density. How can I do it using tensorflow?

For example:

```
likelihood = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc = [0., 0., 0.], scale_diag= [1., 1., 1.])
prior = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc = [0., 0., 0.], scale_diag= [1., 1., 1.])
```

I tried using `tf.multiply(likelihood,prior)` but it gives me datatype error

> Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: tf.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag("MultivariateNormalDiag", batch_shape=(), event_shape=(3,), dtype=float32). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Help much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you take a sample from the distributions and then multiply the samples together?

Answer (score 1):

A `tf.distribution` is an object, and hence can not be used as a Tensor.

You can instead multiply (or sum) the `.prob` (`.log_prob`) methods.